# Same password for all computers?

Tags: password, sync

I have 2 computers running ubuntu. Is is possible to use the same password with both of them? To be more specific: is it possible to sync the password change from one computer to another?

I have same UIDs on both computers and it doesn't necessarily have to be 2-way sync. One of the computers can be the "main" computer where users can change the password and it syncs to the other (or possibly others).

I have 3 users, so LDAP would be a bit overkill in my opinion.

Comment: It might be overkill, but it's designed for this purpose. Why not use it? If you want a setup guide, the LTS server guide has one: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html

Comment: I remember I tried to learn about LDAP once, but didn't fully understand the consept. I guess I'll just have to fire up an virtual machine and start studying if you think it's the best choise. Thanks for the link.